# Обтекание блоком картинки или другого блока. Изгиб стороны блока. Вырезать часть блока

Tags: css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Помогите, пожалуйста, cверстать.

На странице есть логотип и верхний блок над ним изгибается. Как можно сделать такой эффект? Может можно как-то сделать изгиб стороны блока `logo-block`?

В пространстве между белым блоком и логотипом отображается фон с узором. При масштабировании ничего не должно искривляться.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Foto");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  background-color: white;
}

.top,
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.oval {
  width: 18vw;
  height: 4vw;
  background: #969696;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo-block">
      <div class="oval">
        <p class="logo">Logo</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

быстренько состряпал, думаю идея вам будет понятна)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: gray;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}

.logo::after {
  content: "";
  width: 220px;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" role="banner">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Оно то неплохо, но если на фоне картинка с узором, ты ее так не вырежешь чтобы все ровненько легло

Comment: @juliweb, с чего вы это взяли?)